# Non-managed objects in Spring application (best practice)

Tags: java, spring, oop

I have been working on a few web applications and REST web services recently (Spring IoC/MVC/Data JPA etc). They usually follow the same pattern: Controller classes --> Service classes (which have several "utility"/business logic classes autowired) --> Spring Data Repositories.

Pretty much all of the classes above are Spring singletons. I feel like this makes the code and some functions within a class dirtier; for example, I can't have a state in a class, I need to pass a lot parameters between methods, and I don't really like having more than 1-2 parameters (although I know sometimes it is necessary).

I was wondering how this problem is overcome in the big (e.g. enterprise) kind of application.

- Is it a common practice to use non-Spring managed classes in the Spring application? If so, how do you pass dependencies into it (the ones that would normally be autowired)? If I use constructor injection for example, then I need to autowire all necessary dependencies into the class that creates the object and I wanted to avoid that. Also, I don't really want to be messing with load time weaving etc. to autowire beans into non-Spring objects.
- Is using prototype scoped beans a good solution? The only thing is that I need to use AOP's scoped proxies (or method injection etc) to make sure that I get a new instance for any bean that is autowired into a singleton in the first place. Is that a "clean" and reliable option (i.e., is it certain that there will be no concurrency type of issues)? Can I still autowire any singletons into those classes with no issues?

Does anyone that worked on a large system (and actually managed to keep the structure not "bloated" and clean) have any recommendations? Maybe there are some patterns I am not aware and could use?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't have state in a class"? Generally speaking, the infrastructure bits are considered "setup" state, set when the bean is instantiated but constant for its lifetime.

Comment: I mean I cant have instance variables in Spring singletons because they are not thread safe as far as I know.

Comment: It's perfectly safe and customary to use instance variables; look at any Spring tutorial (including the official Get Started guides). As long as you configure everything at startup, there's no threading problem.

Comment: There might be a few ways to do this. One is custom scopes, another one is to use objects to represent the things you want to process, and those objects encapsulate all the required state and might have references to the services, or the services can be injected. For the first approach, I found really useful to try [DIY-DI](http://misko.hevery.com/2010/05/26/do-it-yourself-dependency-injection/) to learn what a custom scope is. The second approach is (in my view) a consequence of using [double dispatch pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: @Augusto It looks like the entire question is a result of a misunderstanding of bean lifecycle; the simplest approach (using instance variables initialized during startup) is perfectly fine.

Comment: @chrylis I always thought that any Spring singleton is not thread safe by nature, i.e. there is only one copy of the class per container, so if we have instance variables in it, multiple threads will be changing the same values potentially at the same time. Are you saying that this assumption is wrong?

Comment: Multiple threads should not be *changing* the instance variables. Instead, beans are normally configured so that dependencies (such as other services) are set up at initialization and then not changed after that; service calls use local variables only, which are thread-safe. Perhaps you should include a concrete example.

Comment: @chrylis I didnt mean any instance variables that are dependencies of the current class and being injected by Spring - of course I shouldnt be changing them and that was my whole point. What I am trying to find out how I can have objects with instance variables within my service classes to perform some business processing and (if possible) keep all advantages of Spring DI in a clean way. I think you misunderstood the question, but most likely its my fault as English is not my first language and I am probably not explaining my problem correctly so apologies.

Comment: Please provide a specific example. It sounds like maybe either your services are trying to do too many things at once, or you should consider something like the Command Object pattern, but it's hard to say.

Comment: _"I think you misunderstood the question, but most likely its my fault as English is not my first language"_ Your language skills are not the problem. You didn't really explain what you want to achieve. Neither did you provide a concrete example. The problems you tried to explain are design problems and don't have much to do with Spring. E.g. if services are bloated then it's not the fault of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is well designed, you must not worry about about IoC implementation of DI. The pattern that you have mentioned /Controller Layer -> Service Layer -> Data Access Layer/ is good in practice, and it is ok that these singleton objects does not have state because of rule of OOP: "Think about objects as service providers that does one thing well". Models can have state as JPA units for storing something in Database. Is not mandatory that in large systems you will have dirty code how you mentioned passing a lot of parameters, it just depends on your design decision that will need a deeper construction.